# Can't format time from Time Picker

Tags: android, android-timepicker

Currently trying to get two different values from the time picker reminderHour, which is the selectedHour and reminderMin which is the selectedMin. Thought I had it working perfectly but found another error this morning.

```
eReminderTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
                mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(AddPayment.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {



                        reminderHour = selectedHour;
                        reminderMin = selectedMinute;


                        if (selectedHour < 10)
                        {
                            if(selectedMinute == 0)
                            {
                                eReminderTime.setText("0" + selectedHour + ":00" + selectedMinute);
                            }
                            else if(selectedMinute < 10)
                            {
                                eReminderTime.setText("0" + selectedHour + ":0" + selectedMinute);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                eReminderTime.setText("0" + selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                            }
                        }

                        if (selectedHour == 0)
                        {
                            if(selectedMinute == 0)
                            {
                                eReminderTime.setText("0" + selectedHour + ":00" + selectedMinute);
                            }
                            else if(selectedMinute < 10)
                            {
                                eReminderTime.setText("0" + selectedHour + ":0" + selectedMinute);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                eReminderTime.setText("0" + selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                            }
                        }

                        if(selectedMinute == 0)
                        {
                            eReminderTime.setText("" + selectedHour + ":00" + selectedMinute);
                        }
                        if(selectedMinute < 10)
                        {
                            eReminderTime.setText("" + selectedHour + ":0" + selectedMinute);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            eReminderTime.setText( "" + selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                        }


                    }
                }, hour, minute, true);

                mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
                mTimePicker.show();

            }
        });
```

That's the code for my Time Picker. I don't want the time joined up all together because I need the hour value stored separately from the minute value.

I tried looking up SimpleDateFormat but I couldn't get it working. This is the code I tried

```
                    SimpleDateFormat simpleHour = new SimpleDateFormat("kk");
                    SimpleDateFormat simpleMin = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");

                    formatHour = simpleHour.format(selectedHour);
                    formatMin = simpleMin.format(selectedMinute);

                    reminderHour = Integer.parseInt(formatHour);
                    reminderMin = Integer.parseInt(formatMin);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), formatHour, 0).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), formatHour, 0).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because individual **hh** and **mm** aren't valid formats. Try to combine the minute and hour values together and when you receive the combined value, seperate them via `split()`

e.g;

```
 SimpleDateFormat simpleHour= new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
 String strTime = sdf.format(new Date());
 String[] pieces=strTime.split(":"); 
 Log.i("Hour: ",pieces[0]);
 Log.i("Miniute: ",pieces[1]);
```

Comment: Edited my post, originally had kk for the hour, that's what it showed in the Java page for SimpleDateFormat

Comment: With kk for the hour and mm for the min, I got 00, 01, 00, 01 printed off I think

Comment: what happens if you put hh or HH?

Answer (score 0):

What output do you want exactly?
If it's just something like:

`01:32`

Then it's simple to generate a string yourself rather than worrying about date formats etc.

```
//Add leading zeros if required
String hours = (String) ((selectedHour < 10) ? "0" + selectedHour 
                                             : Integer.toString(selectedHour));
String minutes = (String) ((selectedMinute < 10) ? "0" + selectedMinute 
                                             : Integer.toString(selectedMinute));
String prettyTime = hours + ":" + minutes;
```

Comment: Yeah a 24 output hh:mm, so 5pm would be 17:00. What does the '?' mean in that code?

Comment: It's the 'ternary operator'. Basically you can read the `?` as "if the preceding expression is true, then the value is" and the `:` as "else the value is".

Comment: This should produce the time as a 24hr string as you require